# How should a global variable be defined to be accessible across a hierarchy of modules in Python?

Tags: python, scope, namespaces

I can't work out how to make a variable in a 'supervising program' (test.py) available through a hierarchy of modules.  That is, I would like to define a variable in a program and make it available to subsequent (imported) .py files.

If I define the variable `my_proc` in 'test.py', it is usable in that file as it stands, as `my_proc`.  However, if I refer to that name in an imported module, the variable is unknown... and there is no concept of `main.my_proc` in Python.

Similarly, if I define this variable in an imported file (globals.py), the variable thus defined will only be known as `globals.my_proc`.  Even if I assign `globals.my_proc` to `my_proc`, the variable is still unknown in an imported file (testmod.py).

Is there any relatively clear way of doing what I describe... to have a generic definition of a global variable that is not bound to the module in which it's defined?

The alternative is to 'parameterize' everything (which I understand is Python's way)... but it means the parameter list of relatively simple functions will need to be quite long when 'context' needs to be communicated down a long function call path.

The ultimate intention is to have a global variable that is the name of the program.  So, any messaging, printed output, etc can be formatted like:-

```
 test: Working on file 'data1.dat'...
 test: ERROR: Invalid format at line 232.  Continuing...
 test: 'data1.dat' processed.
 test: Synchronizing with I/O port..  Done (23 secs)
 ...
```

It would also be useful in a traceback situation when this program is called by another program.

I understand that the logging facilities in Python might be used for such things but I'm trying to get something simple working quickly... and I'm finding I'm spending more time on dealing with 'core language' issues (like how variables are scoped and referenced through the hierarchy of modules) than developing my program...  and I find the standard Python traceback output too detailed and some of my users find such displays disconcerting.

I tried to read the various Python documentation sources but find them very unclear.  I come from a history of decades of dealing with BASIC, C, Perl and other languages and just can't get my head to 'twig' onto how Python does its thing...

Running Anaconda's Python v3.6.5 under Windows 10.

Example code follows.

Thanks.

**test.py:**

```
import os

import testmod

# ---- Test 1: Define my_proc locally
#      my_proc is unknown/unusable in testmod.func1

#my_proc = os.path.basename(__file__)
#print("main: my_proc=", my_proc)
#testmod.func1(34)

# ---- Test 2: Define my_proc in globals.py
#      my_proc is unknown/unusable here in test.py

import globals
# won't work ... print("main: my_proc=", my_proc)
print("main: globals.my_proc=", globals.my_proc)
my_proc = globals.my_proc  # this also won't work

testmod.func1(34)
```

**testmod.py:**

```
# import globals

def func1(val):
   print("parent", my_proc, "value=", val)
```

**globals.py:**

```
import os

# this is no good anyway, as __file__ here is 'globals.py' and not 'test.py'
my_proc = os.path.basename(__file__)

print("in globals: my_proc=", my_proc)
```

Comment: "The alternative is to 'parameterize' everything (which I understand is Python's way)... but it means the parameter list of relatively simple functions will need to be quite long when 'context' needs to be communicated down a long function call path." It's not just "Python's way", it's the software engineering best practice to minimize global mutable state.

Comment: `globals` is a builtin function in python. Try renaming your `globals.py` file to something else.